# Passar Token pelo header a cada requisição AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Estou implementando tokens em um sistema, já tenho o `token` gerado e salvo o mesmo no `sessionStorage`. Como posso criar um serviço ou interceptor pra colocar esse token no `Header` de cada requisição?

Atualmente faço os serviços que são responsáveis pela requisição da seguinte forma:

```
angular.module("Security").factory("usuarioAPI", function ($http, config) {


  var _autenticar = function(usuario){
    return $http.post(config.baseURL + '/SecurityVraptor/usuario/', usuario);
  };

  var _getUsuarios = function(){
    return $http.get(config.baseURL + '/SecurityVraptor/usuario/listarTodos');
  };

  return {
    autenticar: _autenticar,
    getUsuarios: _getUsuarios
  };
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O modo como faço atualmente é carregar ele automaticamente no inicio do `factory` e depois apenas fazer a requisição onde eu precisar. A única diferença é que eu utilizo o `localStorage` ao invés do `sessionStorage`, mas isso fica facilmente à seu critério.

Exemplo:

```
var minhaToken;

function setToken() {
    minhaToken = localStorageService.get('tokenName'); //tokenName é um exemplo do nome da `data` aramazenada na storage
};

function getToken () {
   return minhaToken;
};

return {
    setToken: setToken(),
    getToken: getToken
};
```

E quando for necessário obter o token, digamos que dentro de um controller, basta você fazer a solicitação:

```
$scope.token = usuarioAPI.getToken();
```

Deste modo você pode armazenar ela dentro do seu serviço e solicitar sempre que necessário.

---

**Observação importante:**

Eu usei `localStorageService.get` pois é o plugin (de terceiros - não nativo do AngularJS) que utilizo. Você pode escolher dentre as mais diversas opções qual você irá utilizar, seja ele um plugin terceiro ou do próprio `AngularJS`, [veja este link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies). Eu particularmente prefiro [usar este aqui](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage), pois tem mais liberdade e mais opções que o do `AngularJS`.

---

#### Editado:

Para enviar os parâmetros nas suas requisições, você precisa mesclar eles com as que você já possui - presumo eu que seja o `config.baseUrl` se não, você pode criar uma variável dentro do `factory` e depois passar para o `$http`. Veja:

```
var configHeader;

function setToken() {
    minhaToken = localStorageService.get('tokenName'); //tokenName é um exemplo do nome da `data` aramazenada na storage
    if(minhaToken){
        configHeader = {headers:  {
            'token': minhaToken,
            //e/ou outros valores
        }
    } else {
        //Outra lógica caso o usuario ainda não tenha autenticado.
    };
};

return $http.post(config.baseURL + '/SecurityVraptor/usuario/', usuario, configHeader );
return $http.get(config.baseURL + '/SecurityVraptor/usuario/listarTodos', configHeader );
```

Obs.: Há um tempo atrás parei de usar deste modo por umas mudanças internas no trabalho e comecei a usar diretamente na `url`, mas é completamente a seu critério. Também posso estar errando na syntax, pois faz tempo que não mexo nisso, mas acho que você pode pegar a ideia já.

Nas referências do `AngularJS` na área de `$http` tem a informação da ordem dos objetos, veja: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Entendi, eu fiz com interceptor porém estou tendo problemas. Pois assim todas as requisições são interceptadas e a primeira requisição  que é a do login e a que grava os dados no sessionStorage não poderia ser interceptada

Comment: E como você faz pra passar o token no header a cada requisição?

Comment: E se você mover o login para um serviço separado sem um interceptor? Eu, por exemplo, possuo o módulo `auth` que gerencia somente a autenticação/criação de conta. A partir dai, eu utilizo essa lógica, de obter o token (porém dentro do .run) e faço as verificações a partir dali direto no resolve do meu state. Quando ao header, vou atualizar a resposta.

Comment: Verdade, vou tentar deixar o login em um serviço separado.

Comment: @Techies editei a resposta.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, consegui resolver. Vou tentar aprimorar o código.

Comment: Ótimo! Bom trabalho!

Answer (score 3):

Utilize um `Interceptor` para inserir o *bearer token* em todas as suas requisições. A implementação a seguir utiliza `localstorage` para armazenamento.

```
app.factory('BearerAuthInterceptor', function ($window, $q) {
    return {
        request: function(config) {
            config.headers = config.headers || {};
            if ($window.localStorage.getItem('token')) {

                config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + 
                $window.localStorage.getItem('token');
            }
            return config || $q.when(config);
        },
        response: function(response) {
            if (response.status === 401) {
                //  Redirect user to login page / signup Page.
            }
            return response || $q.when(response);
        }
    };
});

// Registra BearerAuthInterceptor no stack do provedor $http.
app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('BearerAuthInterceptor');
});
```

[Fonte](https://gist.github.com/antoniocapelo/96c3d7989cf19a4f49e4).

Answer (score 0):

Você pode configurar suas requisições para usar sempre o token que definir.

```js
$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token;
```